# Why does this suggested edit have no diff?

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, diff

[This suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/86145) has no diff. I don't just mean there are no visible differences, I mean there is no button to show the HTML or the markdown diff.

[image: screenshot]

Either this is some kind of null edit that should have been rejected at submission time, or this is some UI bug where it's not showing what's been changed. There was no concurrent edit that might have introduced a race condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly its a bug, but a pretty subtle one.

What happened is that the user suggested a nonsense space only edit to the title of the question. The diff for titles does not show such meaningless edits.

I just committed a fix to disallow these kind of edits in future.

Comment: Looks like the bug still exists. See [this suggested edit](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/1847) in response to [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/111502/134327).

Comment: Looks like another occurrence found in the wild: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124051/what-has-been-edited-here

Comment: Well I "really" fixed it this time ... the code was all hooked up but the function I used did not work as intended. @Giles