# Was the user allowed to suggest an edit without  editing  the  post?

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does this suggested edit have no diff?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101035/why-does-this-suggested-edit-have-no-diff)

I found a [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/132347) where the user seems not to have edited anything.

[image: screenshot]

Is it possible, or the suggested edit is not showing correctly the suggested edit?

**Update:** This has been already reported, but the other question is tagged [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), while the same issue showed up again.

Comment: In an attempt to replicated the issue, I've submitted an edit which doesn't change the content and only replaces the paragraph formatting with HTML equivs. The submission went through, but I have no idea if the changes will show up in the diff. Can someone confirm?

Comment: Which was the post that you edited?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/1846 . Nevermind, that wasn't it. The markdown diff still showed the diff. Silly me.

Comment: Finally, a repro! http://meta.stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/1847

Comment: Has the bug been fixed? If it hasn't, then shouldn't the earlier post be *un-status-completed* if this one is to be closed as a dup?

Comment: @Dori: Why did you close this as a duplicate to a [status-completed] bug, when this is obviously not completed, as it still occurs? At least remove the [status-completed] from the other question then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've submitted an [edit suggestion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/1847) which adds extra spaces between words in the title, and lo and behold, we get no diffs.

This looks like the same bug as described here: [Why does this suggested edit have no diff?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/101035/134327)

Comment: It is a bug, then.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the sources of the edits, there is indeed no difference (compare [suggested post](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/132347/view-source) to [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/048a930a-8b1e-402f-b6bd-3394456c7527/view-source), but you have to set the width of the original post to 100% using Firebug though).

Perhaps the edit comment is regarded as data for the 30 characters limit?

Comment: If it so, that is not what I would expect, and it would be a workaround for the "more than 6 characters edit" limit there is for suggested edits.